# How to increase Angular timeout?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, angular

I have a program written in angular, and because im doing something in the browser that takes some time im getting 504 gateway timeout...how can I make the timeout bigger?

Answer (score 2):

This is an error message produced by the server and needs to be fixed there.

See for example https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/504-gateway-time-out-using-nginx/

Comment: so maybe I need to change the Play timeout? @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: What is the "Play timeout"?

Comment: I meant increase POST timeout play, I dont know to tell you if its possible or what is it but since im using post to do something in my page that hold it from being active and im using play so I thought maybe its possible @ GünterZöchbauer

Comment: As mentioned, it's a server error and you need to fix it on the server. If the server sends 504 it doesn't matter how long the client wants to wait for the response.

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming from service, you cannot handle from UI. This needs to be fixed from backend. However you can handle this kind of errors in UI.

```
.success( function( data, status, headers, config )
```

status will give you all status codes.

[For more Info click here](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/03/catch-connection-timeout-error-catch.html)